# Piped search queries in vim or less

Tags: vim, regular-expression, io-redirection, pipe, less

I would like to be able to search a log file for lines that being with ^2014-02-18 15:30:[0-9:,]* and have UserName:someguy much later in the same line.  I am sure I could do a regex to include any number of characters, digits and spaces before that point, but I would like to know if I could effectively do something like `/^2014-02-18 15:30:[0-9:,]* | /UserName:someguy`  meaning pipe the results of the first search through the second search, while still in vim or less.  Obviously I could do this with grep externally.

Comment: How about `grep /^2014-02-18 15:30:[0-9:,]* | /UserName:someguy | vim -`. It will open the contents in vim editor with only the lines having the above patterns in it.

Answer (score 2):

```
:v/^2014-02-18 15:30:/d
```

in `vi` deletes all lines except those matching that pattern. Then you can filter more with:

```
:v/UserName:someguy/d
```

Though you could do it in one go with:

```
:v/^2014-02-18 15:30:.*UserName:someguy/d
```

In `less`, type `&` and then `^2014-02-18 15:30:.*UserName:someguy`